# Search for file in drive without filesystem and partitions

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a drive without any file system or partitions available. I copy there file with dd command. Is there a program which can search such drive for file headers or something like this and thus recover the file? The program must not deal with file system, since there is no such.

Comment: Maybe you could do a `grep` or `hd | grep` trick on the drive?

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the file with `dd`, you can just copy it back with `dd` :-).

`dd` will put the file at the beginning of the drive (unless you used the `seek=` parameter). So just read it back using

```
dd if=/dev/mydevice of=/tmp/rescued_file bs=1M count=<filesize in megabyte>
```

The only problem is that there is no way to tell where the file ends (unless you know that the file has some sort of end marker), so you'll have to give the file size explicitly.

There *are* programs for finding files in a disk or drive image, by just looking for bytes that look like a file in a certain format, but these necessarily only work for certain types of files. One example is [PhotoRec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhotoRec) for finding photos.